# How to transfer single line diagram into simulink using simpowersystems (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, simulink, kalman-filter, simpowersystems

[Here is my example of single line diagram that i want to transfer into the simulink](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LrKr.png) I had a single line diagram and I want to convert it into simulink using Matlab. The problem is i did't find the bus bar in the simulink. Can anyone help me please?

Comment: I think you'll find that the signal used to connect the blocks (i.e. the black lines in the model) are the busbars.  There is no special block.

Comment: In Matlab there are bus creator ad bus selector. Is it same with bus bar?

Comment: The 'Bus' in `Bus Creator` and `Bus Selector` is used to signify a grouping of signals.  Those blocks are used for being able to group a bunch of individual signals into one structure of signals, so that when you draw signals in your model you don't have to draw lots of lines, rather you can draw one line and then 'pick off' signals of interest when they need to be used.  As such, they are not bus bars in the sense of a line diagram.

Comment: I think the OP means a "bus bar" in power systems terminology, as opposed to a Simulink bus. There is no bus bar block in SimPowerSystems, see [this thread](http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/238535) on the same topic.

Comment: Thank you for the explanations.